Constraint Layout items overlapping: Smart wrap text does not work when two opposing items intertwine
I want to make a list item which contains two texts , one anchored to the start of parent and one to the end of parent, I want the space to be dynamically handled each time and if too long it should wrap text and break line, my problem is that I'm using this item everywhere, sometimes Text1 takes up more space than Text2 and vice versa, this makes using Row with weight not useful, I tried using constraint layout, with top, bottom and start/end constraints, but this makes the texts overlap when too long.

This is my constraint layout approach:
val offset: Dp = 8.dp
val modifier = if (onClick != null) {
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .height(rowHeight)
        .clickable(
            onClick = onClick
        )
} else {
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(widthPercentage)
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = rowHeight)
}

ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = modifier
) {
    val (titleRef, infoRef, disclosureRef) = createRefs()

    Text(
        text = title,
        color = titleColor,
        style = titleStyle,
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(titleRef) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = horizontalPadding)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            }
    )

    Text(
        text = infoText,
        color = infoTextColor,
        style = infoStyle,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(infoRef) {
                if (showDisclosure) {
                    end.linkTo(disclosureRef.start, margin = offset)
                } else {
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = horizontalPadding)
                }
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
            }
    )

    if (showDisclosure) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_disclosure_gray),
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(disclosureRef) {
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = horizontalPadding - offset)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }
        )
    }
}

And the row approach which does not give me flexibility, when wanting different text having the bigger weight each time:
val offset: Dp = 8.dp
val modifier = if (onClick != null) {
    Modifier
        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 35.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .padding(vertical = verticalPadding)
        .clickable(
            onClick = onClick
        )
} else {
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(widthPercentage)
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .padding(vertical = verticalPadding)
        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = rowHeight)
}

Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = title,
        color = titleColor,
        style = titleStyle,
        maxLines = 2,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(start = horizontalPadding)
    )

    val trailingPadding = if (showDisclosure) {
        offset
    } else {
        horizontalPadding
    }

    Text(
        text = infoText,
        color = infoTextColor,
        style = infoStyle,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1.5f)
            .padding(start = horizontalPadding, end = trailingPadding)
    )

    if (showDisclosure) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_disclosure_gray),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = offset)
                // .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        )
    }
}

What I am expecting :


Please try to apply the weight Modifier to the first Text Composable as follows:
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            text = "ABC DEF"
        )
        Text(text = "1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000")
    }
}

Jetpack Compose measures the unweighted children first, then it distributes the remaining space between the children that have the weight Modifier set.

The parent will divide the horizontal space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

Output:


Note that if the second Text might fill the whole screen width, you need to specify a max width of the second Text to prevent it from filling the whole screen width and pushing the first Text off. You can try this as follows:
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        text = "ABC DEF"
    )

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.widthIn(max = screenWidth - 150.dp),  // first Text will always have 150dp space
        Text(text = "1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000")
    )

}


I want the second text to be prioritised with taking space, and the first to wrap to multiple lines if needed, and my understanding of compose, was that it measures the space for the first element first, so the weight didn't do anything in my case ,
{
Text(text = "ABC DEF" )
Text(
modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
text = "1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000"
)

When you apply the weight on the first Text as shown in my answer, Jetpack Compose will measure the second Text first. Please test my code and let me know if it works. If it works, please consider to mark this answer as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of this answer.

I edited my post again, there is some drawback. Can it happen that the second text is longer than the screen width? Then we will have to look for another solution.

Yes, it can happen, It would be great if i can handle when it exceeds a specific width, or maybe do a minimum width for the other text so it doesn't disappear

See my edited answer. I hope this works.
